# Spring MVC and freemarker java annotation configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I'm trying to use `freemarker` as my template engine in my project, my views are .JSP files but with nothing of jsp code inside them, I can change them to .html but I also tried that and I get the same error

here is my JavaConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"configuracion", "controladores", "seguridad"})
public class ConfigMVC extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/");

    }

 @Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() {

        FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();

        freeMarkerConfigurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/views/");
        freeMarkerConfigurer.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

        return freeMarkerConfigurer;
    }

@Bean
    public FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver() {

        FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        viewResolver.setCache(false);   //Set to true during production
        viewResolver.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        viewResolver.setOrder(0);

        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

here is my Initializer class

```
public class WebInicializar extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{RootConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{ConfigMVC.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        Filter[] singleton = {new CORSFilter()};
        return singleton;
    }

    @Override
    protected DispatcherServlet createDispatcherServlet(WebApplicationContext servletAppContext) {
        final DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = (DispatcherServlet) super.createDispatcherServlet(servletAppContext);
        dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
        return dispatcherServlet;
    }
```

My Root Config

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"controladores", "seguridad"})
@Import({ConfigMVC.class, SeguridadConfig.class})
public class RootConfig {

}
```

My Spring Version is `4.2.5.RELEASE` and my freeMarker version is `2.3.21`

This is the error when I lauch my web app

```
Advertencia:   StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: Servlet.service() for 

servlet dispatcher threw exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'login' in servlet with name 'dispatcher'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1226)
```

Comment: change your view resolver suffix to .html

Answer (score 1):

Freemarker uses prefix that set in FreemarkerConfigurer.
You need to remove setPrefix from FreeMarkerViewResolver